# migrate querie update in sybase to oracle

Tags: oracle, database-migration, sybase

hi guys i need migrate this querie to oracle

```
UPDATE t_tel
   SET fec_hora = convert(datetime,substring(date_call,1,8) + " " + hour_init)
```

I know very little about the database, pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think (I don't know Sybase so I looked at documentation; it would be simpler if you explained what you want to get as a result based on input (i.e. `DATE_CALL` and `HOUR_INIT` values).

Therefore, a presumption:

- `date_call` *looks like* a date, where first 8 characters represent day, month and year - but I don't know in which format so I presumed it is `ddmmyyyy`. If it is not, you'll have to use correct format
- `hour_init` contains *time* - again, format is unknown, so I presumed it is `hh24mi`

If that's so, you'd

```
update t_tel set
  fec_hora = to_date(substr(date_call, 1, 8) || ' ' || hour_init,
                     'ddmmyyyy hh24mi'
                     );
```

Format mask `ddmmyyyy hh24mi` might need to be changed if source data looks differently.